# PROLOG with lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda, prolog

Is there any Java PROLOG implementation that supports lambda expressions? I know that there are Java implementations of other languages that support lambda expressions, such as LISP and Clojure, but I really need a PROLOG implementation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Prolog_implementations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lean Prolog is implemented in Java and can run Logtalk, which makes lambda expressions available to to all [supported backend Prolog compilers](http://logtalk.org/compatibility.html). For an overview of Logtalk's lambda expressions syntax see e.g.:

[https://logtalk.org/2009/12/08/lambda-expressions-in-logtalk.html/](https://logtalk.org/2009/12/08/lambda-expressions-in-logtalk.html)

For usage examples see:

https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/tree/master/examples/lambdas

Answer (score 3):

There is an Prolog lambda implementation by Ulrich Neumerkel. SWI-Prolog for example supports it. If you did a search in Stackoverflow:

```
[swi-prolog] lambda
```

you can also find quite a few answers using it for solutions.

Also, the web-page that [explains it all](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord)

Comment: Ulrich's lambda library is a Prolog implementation but not an *ISO* Prolog implementation (e.g. it uses a non ISO standard predicate strip_module/3 and a non ISO standard directive meta_predicate/1). It also requires a Prolog compiler supporting a module system not conforming with the ISO Prolog standard for modules.

Comment: @PauloMoura: Please read [this implementation](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord#implementation)! Neither does it contain strip_module/3 nor meta_predicate nor any module reference. The implementation for SWI that you mention does take into account several implementation-specific features of SWI including the ones you mention. But there are even further ones you missed.

Comment: Your link points to a section in that web page whose first sentence reads "Here is the FULL implementation including manual." (emphasis mine). Regarding other stuff I missed, I did write "(e.g. ...)", which is an abbreviation for "for example".

Comment: @PauloMoura: The entire mechanism for lambdas is fully ISO Prolog, that's what you were questioning. For SWI, lambdas are put into a module respecting SWI's module system.

Comment: May I suggest you edit the section you cite (http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord#implementation) and RENAME the first sentence link text which currently reads "full implementation including manual"? The word "full" strongly suggests that the rest of that section contains essential but incomplete code for your implementation. The word "full" is at odds with your comments here. But you can easily fix that.

Comment: @Boris: My previous comment is a reply to Ulrich's observation.

Answer (score 2):

There are basically two approaches around for lambda expressions in
Prolog, that only address the invocation of lambda expressions and
**not** higher order unification:

- **global-by-default:** The variables in the body of the lambda
  expression are global by default, if they are not mentioned
  by an extra binder.
- **local-by-default:** The variables in the body of the lambda
  expression are local by default, if they are not
  mentioned by an extra binder.

Representatives of local-by-default are for example Ulrich Neumerkel's
library(lambda) or the lambda expressions found in Logtalk. The
global-by-default approach is currently followed by the lambda
expressions found in Jekejeke Prolog.

Both approaches allow to model the same mathematical lambda
expressions and solve the following problems by some further syntax:

- Control of sharing or non-sharing of variables across
  multiple invocations.
- Forcing of alpha conversion for binders and local variables
  in the body of the lambda expression.

Here is an example, factorial via the Y combinator:

- global-by-default: Jekejeke Prolog [API](http://www.jekejeke.ch/idatab/doclet/prod/en/docs/05_run/10_docu/05_frequent/07_theories/13_experiment/03_abstract.html) [Source](http://www.jekejeke.ch/idatab/doclet/blog/en/docs/05_run/05_frequent/experiment/abstract.html)

```
    ?- Y    = F\X^call(X\call(F,call(X,X)),X\call(F,call(X,X))),
       Fact = F\J^H^M^N^N\J^H^M^M\J^H^(N=0,M=1;N>0,H is N-1,call(F,H,J),M is N*J),
       call(Y,Fact,10,R). 
    R = 3628800.
```

- local-by-default: [Ulrich Neumerkel's library(lambda)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl)

```
    ?- Y    = \F^call([F]+\X^call(F,call(X,X)),[F]+\X^call(F,call(X,X))),
       Fact = \F^([F]+\N^([N,F]+\M^(N=0,M=1;N>0,H is N-1,call(F,H,J),M is N*J))),
       call(Y,Fact,10,R).
    R = 3628800.
```

Bye

P.S.: The distinction global-by-default and local-by-default is borrowed
from, page 10:
**The Language Features and Architecture of B-Prolog**
Neng-Fa Zhou, Theory and Practice of Logic Programming, 2011
[http://www.sci.brooklyn.cuny.edu/~zhou/papers/tplp11sips.pdf](http://www.sci.brooklyn.cuny.edu/%7Ezhou/papers/tplp11sips.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

In SWI-Prolog there is `library(yall)` (https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall), which even supports currying:

```
?- use_module(library(yall)).

?- maplist([X,Y]>>(Y #= 2*X), [1,2,3], Ys).
Ys = [2, 4, 6].

?- maplist([X,Y]>>([Z]>>(Z #= X * Y)), [1,2,3], [3,4,5], Ys).
Ys = [3, 8, 15].

?- maplist([X,Y,Z]>>(Z #= X * Y), [1,2,3], [3,4,5], Ys).
Ys = [3, 8, 15].

?- maplist([X]>>([Y]>>([Z]>>(Z #= X * Y))), [1,2,3], [3,4,5], Ys).
Ys = [3, 8, 15].
```

Same with `library(lambda)`:

```
?- maplist(\X^(\Y^(Y #= 2*X)), [1,2,3], Ys).
Ys = [2, 4, 6].

?- maplist(\X^Y^(\Z^(Z #= X * Y)), [1,2,3], [3,4,5], Ys).
Ys = [3, 8, 15].

?- maplist(\X^Y^Z^(Z #= X * Y), [1,2,3], [3,4,5], Ys).
Ys = [3, 8, 15].

?- maplist(\X^(\Y^(\Z^(Z #= X * Y))), [1,2,3], [3,4,5], Ys).
Ys = [3, 8, 15].
```

However the lambdas of `library(lambda)` can also be used to "extract" the values of only some variables of a query:

```
?- Xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], member(X, Xs), 0 #= X mod 2, Y #= X * 2.
Xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
X = 2,
Y = 4 ;
Xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
X = 4,
Y = 8 ;
Xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
X = 6,
Y = 12 ;
false.

?- Y+\(Xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], member(X, Xs), 0 #= X mod 2 Y #= X * 2).
Y = 4 ;
Y = 8 ;
Y = 12 ;
false.
```

Comment: You can also use `library(yall)` to "extract" the values of only some variables of a query": `{Y}/(Xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], member(X, Xs), 0 #= X mod 2, Y #= X * 2)`.

Comment: oh, I was wondering about that! so there are two different syntaxes in the case of `library(yall)`?

Comment: No, there's a single syntax: `{...}/[...]>>Goal`. But both `{...}` and `[...]` are optional if there are not, respectively, *lambda free variables* or *lambda parameters*. See the library documentation or this [blog post](https://logtalk.org/2009/12/08/lambda-expressions-in-logtalk.html) for historical notes on the syntax.